# OpenGL ImageStore slower when storing certain values

Tags: opengl

I am writing on some 3D textures that are defined as follows:

```
layout (binding = 0, rgba8) coherent uniform image3D volumeGeom[MIPLEVELS];
layout (binding = 4, rgba8) coherent uniform image3D volumeNormal[MIPLEVELS];
```

and I am writing the following values

```
float df = dot(normalize(In.WorldNormal), -gSpotLight.Direction);
if(df < 0) df = 0;
else df = 1;
fragmentColor = texture2D(gSampler, In.TexCoord0.xy);
imageStore(volumeGeom[In.GeomInstance], ivec3(coords1), fragmentColor);
imageStore(volumeNormal[In.GeomInstance], ivec3(coords1), vec4(normalize(In.WorldNormal), 1.0));
fragmentColor = vec4(fragmentColor.xyz*CalcShadowFactor(In.LightSpacePos)*df,1.0);
```

as you can see I write the first fragmentColor and I purposely put the other fragmentColor after the store even though I don't do anything with it. This configuration runs at 21 FPS. If I then do this

```
float df = dot(normalize(In.WorldNormal), -gSpotLight.Direction);
if(df < 0) df = 0;
else df = 1;
fragmentColor = texture2D(gSampler, In.TexCoord0.xy);
fragmentColor = vec4(fragmentColor.xyz*CalcShadowFactor(In.LightSpacePos)*df,1.0);
imageStore(volumeGeom[In.GeomInstance], ivec3(coords1), fragmentColor);
imageStore(volumeNormal[In.GeomInstance], ivec3(coords1), vec4(normalize(In.WorldNormal), 1.0));
```

in which the second fragmentColor is computed before and stored in volumeGeom the entire thing runs at 13 FPS. This means that imageStore is running slower depending on the values I am writing in. Is that because of some compiler optimization?
Basically the second fragmentColor is 0 for surfaces that are in shadow or backface the light.

Comment: Unrelated: You can replace your `if` branch which is `df = step(0, df);`, which should be a bit faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how complicated your `CalcShadowFactor` method is, but it is likely that in the first version, the image stores can overlap with your calculation, while in the second, your calculation has to end first before the stores can be called. This, plus the increased register pressure, can be already enough to make the #2 version much slower than the #1.

If this is the complete source code, it is also likely that in the #1 case the call to `CalcShadowFactor` is completely optimized out, as the result is never used (if `fragmentColor` is never read again and is not an output.)

Comment: I think it's more likely that in the first version the `CalcShadowFactor` call is optimized out completely (the OP mentioned they don't do anything with the result).

Comment: Sure, if it's not used at all, then this is another candidate. I'll update my answer accordingly.